# Regular expression with drools (special characters /* )

Tags: java, regex, drools

I'm trying to make a rule to catch invalid characteres. Those are & < > /* ' " --

I already managed to "catch" all the symbols except the /*

**My code is:**

```
rule "Invalid Chars"
when
    c : Class ( field matches ".*[&<>'\"].*|.*(--).*" )
then
    // DO SOMETHING     
end
```

My regex is below. But when I try to add the /* symbol. I get this regex

```
.*[&<>'\"].*|.*(--).*|.*(\/\*).*
```

But when I try to run I get this error:

> line 1:28 no viable alternative at character '*'
>   line 1:33 mismatched character '' expecting '"'
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ### errors ###
>   [Error: illegal escape sequence: *]~

How to "catch" all these invalid characters?

Comment: / is nothing special in regex - you shoudn't need to escape that with \

Comment: shouldn't you escape it with `\\`?

Comment: I escaped / because I was creating the regex in a website, and it said: Error: unescaped forward slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's minimal Test with * escaped but / not:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if("Hallo /* Test ".matches(".*[&<>'\"].*|.*(--).*|.*(/\\*).*")) {
        System.out.println("ILLEGAL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
String pattern = "[&|<|>|'|\"|]|(--)|(\\/\\*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher("YOUR STRING TO FIND MATCHES");
while (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Matched value: " + m.group(0) );
}
```